# order documents with a particular field first in solr

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

I have a solr field namely 'crs_name' which is a multivalued field in solr. But its not present in all the documents.

When I perform a query below

```
http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/institute/select?=*:*&fl=crs_name&wt=json&indent=true
```

I will get response like this

```
response":{"numFound":781,"start":0,"docs":[
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {
        "crs_name":["MBA",
        "B.Tech",]
      },
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {}]
```

Is it possible to display those document first which have the 'crs_name' field in them, for eg --

```
response":{"numFound":781,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "crs_name":["MBA",
        "B.Tech",]
      },
      {
        "crs_name":["B.Tech",]
      },
      {
        "crs_name":["MBA",]
      },
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your schema.xml, so your crs_name field type will have this param - `sortMissingLast=true`.

It should help you. For more info take a look here - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Data_Types